# Resize Buffered Image without creating new instance (java)

Tags: java, image, user-interface, bufferedimage, buffered

I was wondering if there is a way to resize a BufferedImage without creating a new instance of another image. I am wondering this because I think that it will be inefficient to create a new image each time I want to resize a BufferedImage for my application. Here is some code I've seen that explains what I don't want:

```
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) { 
    Image tmp = img.getScaledInstance(newW, newH, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D g2d = dimg.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    return dimg;
}
```

```
public static BufferedImage scale(BufferedImage src, int w, int h)
{
    BufferedImage img = 
            new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    int x, y;
    int ww = src.getWidth();
    int hh = src.getHeight();
    int[] ys = new int[h];
    for (y = 0; y < h; y++)
        ys[y] = y * hh / h;
    for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        int newX = x * ww / w;
        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            int col = src.getRGB(newX, ys[y]);
            img.setRGB(x, y, col);
        }
    }
    return img;
}
```

```
private BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage src, int targetSize) {
    if (targetSize <= 0) {
        return src; //this can't be resized
    }
    int targetWidth = targetSize;
    int targetHeight = targetSize;
    float ratio = ((float) src.getHeight() / (float) src.getWidth());
    if (ratio <= 1) { //square or landscape-oriented image
        targetHeight = (int) Math.ceil((float) targetWidth * ratio);
    } else { //portrait image
        targetWidth = Math.round((float) targetHeight / ratio);
    }
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(targetWidth, targetHeight, src.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR); //produces a balanced resizing (fast and decent quality)
    g2d.drawImage(src, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    return bi;
}
```

**Thank you for any responses!**

Comment: I think the `getScaledInstance()` method is resource efficient because it kind of only copies everything.

Comment: And it doesn't have to calculate everything again.

Comment: Yeah but that returns an Image, not a BufferedImage

Comment: That image could even hold a reference to img and the new size... What is the class name of the new Image instance?

Comment: Because Image is an abstract class...

Comment: So should I cast it to a BufferedImage?

Comment: No, print the class(`.getClass().getCanonianName()`) of the object and share the output.

Comment: Of the original BufferedImage?

Comment: No, of the scaled instance

Comment: I think it's this: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage

Comment: i can't forget that nice article *the perils of scaled instance* https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983611